# Additional content in Wordpress - possible use of Custom Taxonomies

Tags: wordpress

I'm fairly new to the Custom Taxonomies in Wordpress, but I wanted to see if I can use this feature to achieve a list of items that link of to pages within my site.

Here is the final HTML I am looking to output:

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://mywpdomain.com/page1">Custom Taxonomy 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://mywpdomain.com/page2">Custom Taxonomy 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://mywpdomain.com/page3">Custom Taxonomy 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://mywpdomain.com/page1">Custom Taxonomy 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see above I have various taxonomy items (i.e. 1 & 4) both linking to the **same** URL.

So I am looking to see if it is possible to:

1. **Setup Custom Taxonomies with two data inputs** (name & custom URL) that I could reference in my theme
2. Alternatively, I would just create another HTML section where I could define the content (& links) in each post. (Almost as if it was a secondary 'content' area).

I would prefer not to use a plugin if possible, as I am attempting to maintain autonomy of the background code. Is this possible?

**EDIT:**

Sorry if this wasn't clear. I'm not 100% if Custom Taxonomies is the correct way to go.

Basically, I have a list of 'features' that I want to tag on each of my 'portfolio' posts. I want to display these features in a simple (linked) unordered list.

The important thing however is I don't want the list to be linked to a category/archive (like normal tags work). I want to be able to define the URL to an existing 'service' page for each feature, so the user can read more.

Therefore I need to be able to define both the `name` of the feature and the `url` of the page the link should point to.

As the list of 'features' & the pages they point to will always remain the same, I thought Custom Taxonomies may be the solution.

Comment: Sorry but what exactly you want to do ? Each taxonomy has to attach to a post or to a custom post. So you can see the posts of a taxonomy (archive) or a certain post with a taxonomy term you want.

Comment: Do you just want to output all the names of the registered custom taxonomies and then hardcode the links ?

Comment: I've amended the post with some more information, I hope this clarifies. Thank you for taking the time to look at it for me!

Comment: The list of features doesn't appear in the same location as the main post content - hence why I am looking for an alternative solution (otherwise I would simply create the list & link them for each post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a template for each taxonomy term , in your case for each feature.

So ie if you have a term with the name 'premium' you can make a `taxonomy-features-premium.php` template file and place whatever you want.

So on your page where the portfolio post is being display you can show all the features with their permalinks and if you have make the template files for every term when you click on a term will show the template file for the term that you selected.

or inside the template files you can just redirect them to the page you want.

**Update :**

In your single-portfolio.php (the template file responsible for showing the portfolio custom post) you can put somewhere in your code (depending your needs and the style of your page) :

```
echo '<ul>';
echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'features', '<li>', ',</li><li>', '</li>' );
echo '</ul>';
```

Doc : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list or you can use : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms if you want to take more control of your terms.

This would return something like :

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="premium">Premium Feature</a></li> 
    <li><a href="basic">Basic Feature</a></li>
</ul>
```

So now you have all the terms belonging to the specific post. So if you create a `taxonomy-features-premium.php` template file, when the user clicks the Premium Feature link wordpress will show whatever is in that template. Notice that if you don't have a `taxonomy-features-premium.php` template wordpress will search for a `taxonomy-features.php` (that template is usufull if you want all your terms to be shown the same way). More about template hierarchy here : http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display

Now inside the template or you can copy paste the code that you have in your page + add some modifications corresponding to the term or you can just redirect to the page you want :  `wp_redirect(get_permalink( $your_page_id )); exit;`

Comment: Okay, I think I understand the concept, but I don't follow the application. Could you point to any documentation on this?

Comment: Okay this is great! Took me a bit to wrap my head around but it's all working perfectly. I used a conditional statement to define the page ID's for the redirect. I shall post this below for reference.

Comment: `<?php

  $taxID = '';

  if ( is_tax( 'features', 'basic' ) ) {
   $taxID = 75;
  }
  else {
   $taxID = 117;
  }
  
  wp_redirect(get_permalink( $taxID )); exit;
 ?>`